# Highlighting divs without empty spaces in between

Tags: html, css

Given the code in the screenshot,

[image]

I get words highlighted in yellow if I take a note:

[image]

How could I achieve the result where the empty spaces between these words would be highlighted too, so that the whole note is highlighted in yellow?

The span element surrounding all these divs (wrd) is there by chance, so it could easily exist in some other structure.

I thought of wrapping all these divs and apply a style to a container, but the problem is that I can not wrap these words in any container as they may pertain to several notes and some of these notes could even contain a subset of these words or some text after the words I have highlighted (running the risk to break the HTML structure opening and closing divs the wrong way).

The element wrd has no custom CSS style applied.

Comment: just target the span

Answer (score 0):

WRDS element are now spaced like this:

```
<wrd>Content</wrd>`whitespace`<wrd>Content2</wrd>
```

You need to contain whitespaces in the wrd element like this:

```
<wrd>Content </wrd><wrd>Content2 </wrd>
```

Comment: Is the whitespace automagically placed there? If I hardcode a new empty space within a WRD, will i have two whitespaces then?

Comment: I dont know, wrd is custom element, and i can't see your code or styles aplied to the wrd element...

Comment: Thre is a way in js, to generate the span tags between <br> elements, and then aply style to it.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#background{
background-color:yellow;}
```

```html
<span id='background'>This is a sentence</span>
```

Comment: No, I said I can not count on the fact that there is a span there. Thank you anyway